# for loop to get the elements in key value pair

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Im trying to read data from a csv file and want to store it in a key value pair.

code im trying is as follows:

```
csv_data = []
with open('/Users/tejas/textTocsv/pair.csv') as paircsv:
    reader = csv.DictReader(paircsv, delimiter = ',' )
    for row in reader:
        #im stucked over here
```

pair.csv data

```
id   ppid
1    22rt3
12   3456r4
23   w232w
```

I want the data to be in key value pair so that i can use it further in the program.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you want to get key value pairs like `(1, '22rt3')`, `(12, '3456r4)`, etc. you are better of using `csv.reader` rather than `csv.DictReader`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example for storing in a dictionary

```
import csv

csv_data={}

with open("/Users/tejas/textTocsv/pair.csv") as paircsv:
    reader =csv.reader(paircsv)
    for key,value in reader:
        csv_data[key]=value

print(csv_data)
```

Outpt

```
{'id': 'ppid', '1': '22rt3', '12': '3456r4', '23': 'w232w'}
```

Comment: Exception has occurred: ValueError
not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) getting this error

Comment: There may be a problem accessing the file or the file structure is incorrect.

Comment: trying to figure it out,trying all the possibilities which can solve the error

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, but as @Heike pointed out you are better off with a `csv.reader` over a `csv.DictReader` given the structure of your data.  Here is an example of how you can start with csv file and end up with a dictionary for use later in your program.

Example:

```
from io import StringIO
import csv

# Simplified the example using StringIO instead of file I/O.
# Note: replaced spaces with commas as delimeters
paircsv = StringIO("""id,ppid
1,22rt3
12,3456r4
23,w232w
""")

# Commenting this out for StringIO example
# with open('/Users/tejas/textTocsv/pair.csv') as paircsv:

reader = csv.reader(paircsv, delimiter = ',' )

# Construct a dictionary from the key, value pairs in the CSV file
csv_data = {
    key: value
    for key, value in reader
}

print(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'id': 'ppid', '1': '22rt3', '12': '3456r4', '23': 'w232w'}
```

Comment: Exception has occurred: ValueError
not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) getting this error

Comment: My example was designed to work with key value pairs in separated by a comma, not spaces like in your example (see my code comment).  Did you switch your CSV file format to use commas to match the code?

Comment: yes, its working now thank you for your help :)